# Which() condition on matrix

Tags: r, matrix

In R, why in a case when `which()` condition applied on matrix has one row the output is a character but not a matrix with dimension of [1,n]?

For example  `DFmatrix[which(DFmatrix[,1]=="a"),]` will be a matrix in case there are more than one row as output, but of type character otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

`arr.ind` can return array indices

```
( m <- matrix(1:12, 3, 4) )
div.3 <- m %% 3 == 0
which(div.3)
which(div.3, arr.ind = TRUE)
```